# Do there really exist plural forms for "математика" and "физика"?

Tags: множественное-число, математика, физика

The site Викисловарь indicates in the table of different forms of a noun when there is no plural form, such as the page for мясо. I noticed the tables on the pages for математика and физика include plural forms in a regular way (nothing unusual in their appearance like for мясо). This seems weird to me. Is there any reason that "математика" or "физика" would really be used in a plural form?

Describing different branches of math or physics does not involve putting the words "математика" or "физика" in plural, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very fact that some noun has valid plural form doesn't mean that that plural is in active use. In practice it can be used quite rarely. Consider, for instance, "сметана" - we can construct a valid sentence with it, like:

> Меня удивило, что к столу подали самые разные сметаны - были тут жирные, густые, и такие, что по консистенции напоминали почти что молоко, и такие, что были практически как масло.

Will you encounter such usage in real life? Hardly. But that proves nothing.

There are words for which even such artificial example is hard to come up with, they still do have valid plural, for instance, "ненависти", "злобы" and so on.

For "математика" and "физика", however we are in that aspect closer to "сметана". There are still cases where you can use it in plural, [like in](http://studspace.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Math_as_culture.pdf):

> Конечно, сам факт существования разнообразных математик у различных народов ещё не означает того, что они совершенно не совпадают друг с другом, что они абсолютно разные.

or

> Были созданы не только несколько физик, но и огромная свалка взаимоисключающих теорий.

Well, I believe you got the idea.

Even more, speaking of these two particular words, there's another, way less philosophical context where one can use plural: those are school subjects, so you can easily hear something like:

> У нас сегодня отменили обе физики, потому что Ильинична заболела!

Comment: "Новый год — хороший повод оставить все злобы и ненависти позади и начать с чистого листа." Wasn't particularly hard to come up an example

Comment: "Две физики" is singular ;)

Comment: @SergeySlepov got me, fixed the example )

Comment: "Обе" too governs singular.

Comment: @SergeySlepov are you sure? Because "обе красивые", "обе хотят" - or do I miss something?

Comment: О́бе руки́ (Gen. sg.) - на все ру́ки (Nom. pl.). Same with физики.

Comment: Plural example: "Даешь пять математик в неделю!"

Comment: Agreed with @SergeySlepov. Отменили оба труда - singular. You cannot say "отменили оба труды"

Answer (score 1):

The plural forms really do exist and there is a reason for it. The usage of the words is not very common but if you compare completely different approaches to a similar problem, Newtonian mechanics to the Lagrangian one for example, and try to emphasize the fundamental difference between their basic principles then this is one of the common cases for the plural form of this kind of words.

Comment: Can you include examples of sentences reflecting the usage of the plural form to contrast Newtonian and Hamiltonian or Lagrangian mechanics?

Comment: @KCd: _Таким образом, в историческом споре ньютоновой и лагранжевой механик Вы приняли сторону последней_

Comment: @Quassnoi That doesn't appear to answer my question since it is not using the word физика (or математика) in a plural form.

Comment: @KCd: didn't you ask about mechanics in your comment? But either way, here you are: _Квантовая механика привела к созданию атомной и ядерной физик_

Comment: @Quassnoi  does that sound better to you than ".... к созданию атомной и ядерной физики"? For example, would you say ему нравятся классическая и квантовая физики and он изучает древнюю и совеременную математики are correct while ему нравится классическая и квантовая физика and он изучает древнюю и совеременную математику are wrong or at least less standard in some sense?

Comment: I'd prefer the latter version with singular физика and математика. The examples in the answer above are good -- they show that you use plural in this case to somehow stress the distinction between different types of physics/maths. In your sentences you merely state that someone likes both A and B, and I don't feel that using a very uncommon plural in this context is justified. It sort of sticks out, at least I'd stop and think why a plural is used here if I am to encounter such a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

In Russian, the words  *физика* and *математика* are used in the names of the certain areas of physics and mathematics: *ядерная физика, физика твёрдого тела; дискретная математика* etc.

There is such a thing as "a physics" or "a mathematics" in Russian, if you will, and you can list them in a sentence:

> - Таким образом, в историческом споре ньютоновой и лагранжевой механик Вы приняли сторону последней
> - Квантовая механика привела к созданию атомной и ядерной физик
> - Но что же такое конкретная математика на самом деле? Это смесь континуальной и дискретной математик

From Rosenthal et al., *Современный русский язык*:

> Если при имени существительном имеется несколько однородных определений, перечисляющих разновидности предметов, то определяемое существительное может стоять как в единственном, так и во множественном числе.
>
> ...
>
> Форма множественного числа определяемого существительного подчеркивает наличие нескольких предметов, например: *немецкий и французский языки; филологический и исторический факультеты; старшая и младшая дочери* и т.п.

In the examples above, the different areas of physics and mathematics are emphatically distinct, so we put the words *физика* and *математика* in plural.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is NO (for more like official speech). The example given by @Curiosity about "злобы и ненависти" is "simplified speech", просторечие. You can talk like this with your family. But not with your business partner.

But if you mean "two kinds of physics" or "two different approaches in physics", you could say "две разные физики". But that still is  "simplified speech", просторечие. In more strict Russian, it will be exactly "два вида физики", "два разных подхода в физике". Singular form.

Comment: I'm down-voting this because this is just not correct statement. It's used that way de-facto and whatever we personally think will sound better we can not deny that fact.

Comment: @shabunc OK maybe I were to critical